# Contact Duplicate Preventer

Tags: apex

Suppose i have an active Contact with an email address `xyz@gmail.com`. 
If I try to create the 2nd Contact with same email address, it will throw an error, since that email is in use. This works as expected.

However, I'd like to modify this trigger to allow creation of Contacts whose emails are only used by inactive contacts.

Currently my trigger is the following:

```
trigger ContactDuplicatePreventer on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    Map<String, Contact> ConMap = new Map<String, Contact>();
        for (Contact Contact : System.Trigger.new) {

               if ((Contact.Email != null) &&
                (System.Trigger.isInsert ||
                (Contact.Email !=
                    System.Trigger.oldMap.get(Contact.Id).Email))) {


            if (ConMap.containsKey(Contact.Email)) {
                Contact.Email.addError('Another Contact has the same email address.');
            } else {
                ConMap.put(Contact.Email, Contact);
            }
       }
    }

    for (Contact Contact : [SELECT Email FROM Contact
                      WHERE Email IN : ConMap.KeySet()]) {
        Contact newContact = ConMap.get(Contact.Email);
        newContact.Email.addError('A Contact with this E-mail address already exists.');
    }
}
```

Comment: Code in a trigger feels like overkill when you can use the platform's [Duplicate Management](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_prevention_map_of_tasks.htm) feature to find and manage duplicates, all through config.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to add an additional filter on your second query:

```
for (Contact Contact : [SELECT Email FROM Contact
                      WHERE Email IN : ConMap.KeySet() AND Owner.IsActive = true]) {
```

Comment: hi sfdcfox it is not working if i add owner.isActive = true in query

Comment: @user43885 Perhaps there was a misunderstanding. Howe do you define an "inactive contact"?

Comment: Thanks this wroks for (Contact Contact : [SELECT Email FROM Contact
                      WHERE Email IN : ConMap.KeySet() AND Owner.IsActive != true]) {

Comment: Ooops !! seems it's not working it is not throughing any error even if the account is active

Comment: @user43885 Your query (above) only throws errors if the contact owner **is** inactive, which is not what you stated in your question. Also, if you need to filter by account as well, then it becomes `AND (Owner.IsActive = TRUE OR Account.Owner.IsActive = TRUE)`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to filter the query which checks your trigger data against the data in the database.

```
[SELECT Email FROM Contact WHERE Email IN : ConMap.KeySet() AND Owner.IsActive = true]
```

By adding the `AND` clause, you can provide extra filters which the query will satisfy. The filter `Owner.IsActive = true` will only provide contacts with active owners, and when combined with the filter `Email IN : ConMap.KeySet()`, will only provide contacts who are active, and have an email in the keyset.

Comment: can you please let me know where to add the code to check if it is not active